# Why won't my default url page load without /index.html?

Tags: default

I want my URL to display my index.html file as default but only loads an OLD practice html page I uploaded to the FTP a few months ago. How can I make site load on www.me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net rather than its current [www.me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/index.html](http://www.me14ch/leedsnewmedia.net/index.html) ?

(and yes I am aware the index.html looks very blank at the moment, this is because I need to update links in dreamweaver because I moved the file, just want to get the default url working first!) Many thanks

Comment: I am not sure what container you are using but in any tomcat base project you can specify the welcome file in container (web.xml).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what container you are using but in any tomcat base project you can specify the welcome file in container (web.xml).

1. In web.xml

   < welcome-file-list >

   < welcome-file >/index.jsp< /welcome-file >

   < /welcome-file-list >

In apache you can use steps explained [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-display-or-change-a-default-page-other-than-indexhtml/)